# 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again. Get this error when i return from ipay88 payment page

Tags: php, laravel

when i at ipay88 payment page, either the transaction is cancelled or succeeded and return back to my merchant page. i always get this error 
419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.

When i change the route to GET, it show MethodNotAllowedHttpException No Message but with the correct POST data from ipay88. but once i change the route to POST, the session expired 419 error appear. i am new to this, can anyone help to solve this or explain..Thank you so much..

This is my route code

```
//ipay88 response page
Route::post('/post-ipay88','ProductsController@postIPay88');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf). The easiest way to get around this would be to [exclude](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) that particular route from Laravel's CSRF protection.

One way you can do this is by going to your `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` and adding the route to the `$except` array:

```
protected $except = [
    '/post-ipay88'
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day, I has been headache for this issue few days!